# Running aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2 with PKCS11 Received error: Feature not supported on this platform

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, pkcs#11, aws-iot-core

I created a thing on AWS MQTT. And I use softhsm to import private key into a token. The token looks like this:

```
Private Key Object; RSA 
  label:      #####
  ID:         #####
  Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap
  Access:     sensitive
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      #####
  ID:         #####
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap
  Access:     none
```

And then I use `aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2` to connect pkcs11 with the command: `python3 pkcs11_connect.py --endpoint <endpoint> --ca_file <path to root CA> --cert <path to certificate> --pkcs11_lib <path to PKCS11 lib> --pin <user-pin> --token_label <token-label> --key_label <key-label>`

And I received the following output:
Loading PKCS#11 library '/PATH/libsofthsm2.so' ...
Loaded!
**RuntimeError**: 53 (AWS_ERROR_PLATFORM_NOT_SUPPORTED): Feature not supported on this platform

Comment: pkcs11_connect.py is only supported on Unix, what platform you trying to run this? OS details will help

Comment: I am running on my MAC

Comment: It wont work as only Unix is supported for pkcs, incase want to test create a small t3 instance with cloud9 and test it out